# Create generic route-based authorization in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authorization, middleware, laravel-7

I'm coming from conventional PHP background and trying to create my first big project in Laravel.
I usually user User/Role/Permission to manage user permissions in my applications. It works like follows:

- User has many Roles
- Role has many Permissions

to make things simple, I actually used the page names as permissions, so that I check the current page name against user permissions.

That was all easy in PHP, now I am trying to implement a similar approach in Laravel. I have User, Role, Permission models, and I check if user has permission using a method in User model as follows (inspired from a Laracasts tutorial):

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->roles->map->permissions->flatten()->pluck('name')->unique();
}
```

And in my AuthServiceProvider I added the following code:

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $permission){
    return $user->permissions()->contains($permission);
});
```

So if I add some permission (for example 'add_user') to the user, I can simply do the following in the route, and it works just fine:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'You are authorized';
})->name('add_user')->middleware('can:add_user');
```

Now since I have a lot of pages, I wouldn't like to pass specific permission name to the middleware, rather find a better and more generic way.

The only way I could come up with is to use the permission name same as the route name, and create a new middleware to take care of authorization.

So In my solution I added the following middleware class:

```
class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route_name = $request->route()->getName();
        if(!Auth::user()->permissions()->contains($route_name)) {
            throw new \Exception('Not Authorized');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Added it to Kernel.php:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'before' => \App\Http\Middleware\BeforeMiddleware::class,
        ...
    ];
```

And finally changed the route to be as follows:

```
Route::middleware(['before'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/test', function () {
        return 'You are authorized';
    })->name('add_user');

});
```

This way I don't actually have to pass the permission name when I check the permission, and directly get it from the route name.

I have many questions about my solution: is it really a good approach? Does it have any drawbacks? Is there a better approach?

Also I preferred to use AuthServiceProvider instead of the new middleware, but I couldn't retrieve the route name from ServiceProvider scope. Can I somehow use AuthServiceProvider for a similar case?

Sorry if I made the post somehow long, but I needed to be as clear as I could.

Comment: I don't have much advice for this as a full on permission system has so many complexities. I would personally use an existing library. Have you checked out the Spatie Permission library? https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/

Comment: You should read about [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gates), [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies) and authorization in [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests). And +1 for spatie/laravel-permissions.

Comment: @KurtFriars I already created a gate for the middleware. Sorry I missed to mention this in my question, I will update it.

Comment: @Spholt I'd like to write it myself, not only to understand Laravel better, but also to be on top of the code, and easily customize it when required. This whole permission code is not actually very complex.